# Вытащить метаданные из загружаемого файла

Tags: java, servlet, fileupload

Вот мой код:

```
     protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);

    if (isMultipart) {
        FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

        try {
            List items = upload.parseRequest(request);
            //Тут мы уже знаем имя загружаемого файла, и путь на сервере!!!
            Iterator iterator = items.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                FileItem item = (FileItem) iterator.next();


                if (!item.isFormField()) {
                    String fileName = item.getName();

                    if (checkFileType(request, response, fileName)) return;

                    String root = getServletContext().getRealPath("");
                    File path = new File(root + "/uploads");
                    if (!path.exists()) {
                        boolean status = path.mkdirs();
                    }

                    File uploadedFile = new File(path + "/" + fileName);
                    PathOnServer = uploadedFile.getAbsolutePath();
                    item.write(uploadedFile);
                    getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/message.html").forward(
                            request, response);
                }
            }
        } catch (FileUploadException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Как вытащить путь загружаемого файла, который сначала находится на локальной машине, чтобы взять у него метаданные?

Answer (score 1):

Путь уже вытащен.

Можете извлекать метаданные сразу после `item.write(uploadedFile)`.

```
...
item.write(uploadedFile);
// взять метаданные из uploadedFile
...
```

Если обработка планируется в другом потоке, то uploadedFile или путь надо куда-то положить. Туда, где другой поток его обнаружит. Например поместить в глобальную очередь.

```
...
item.write(uploadedFile);
FileHandler.queue.put(uploadedFile); // или FileHandler.queue.put(PathOnServer);
...
```

В потоке-обработчике файлы извлекаются из очереди.

```
public class FileHandler {
    public static Queue queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<File>(); // new LinkedBlockingQueue<String>();
    ...

    public static handleQueue() {
        while (true) {
            File file = FileHandler.queue.take(); // File file = new File(FileHandler.queue.take());
            // взять метаданные из file
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Метод `FileHandler.handleQueue` должен быть вызван из `Thread`.
Это только пример и требует доработки.

Можно путь сохранять в базу данных.

Можно отправить в JMS.

Вариантов море. Главное положить туда, от куда потом обработчик его достанет.

Ещё можно замутить с наблюдением за папкой `uploads`. Тогда про этот путь вообще можно забыть. Но там другие будут заморочки, хотя на самом деле и не сложные.
Суть в том, что сохраняется файл под другим именем, с добавлением расширения например `.tmp`.
После `item.write` он переименовывается по-нормальному, убирается добавка `.tmp`.
Обработчик постоянно следит за папкой `uploads` и как только появляется новый файл с нормальным расширением (не `.tmp`), он извлекает из него метаданные. После переносит обработанный файл в другую папку.
`tmp` нужен чтобы обработчик не пытался обрабатывать частично загруженные файлы, а перенос в другую папку - чтобы не обрабатывать файлы повторно.

Comment: Но я получаю дату создания файла на сервере, а не на локальной машине. То есть файл создан в 2000 году, помещаю на сервер, и получаю дату помещения файла на сервер

Comment: Передача этих данных никак не предусмотрена через  выгрузку файлов на сервер. Я думал у Вас в самом файле хранится что-то, что Вы называете метаданными. Следовало бы ставить верный вопрос. Не про какой-то путь, а как передать метаданные файла на сервер вместе или без самого файла. Тут главная проблема будет как извлечь эти данные в javascript. А передать можно без проблем.

Comment: Посмотрите DOM File API. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Extensions/Using_the_DOM_File_API_in_chrome_code
От туда можно вытянуть только дату модификации файла. Если этого мало, то надо искать другие решения. В IE возможно получится заюзать в javascript какой-нибудь COM-объект для работы с файловой системой. В других браузерах с этим сложней.